# Pyspark : Split dataframe based on contents and extract date from bottom line of split

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a legacy file into a Dataframe and it looks something like below;

```
+-----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|c1         |      c2  | c3       |    c4  |    c5  |    c6  |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| 01        |  B01     |null      |null    |file1   |B01-01  |
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file1   |B01-02  |
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file1   |B01-03  |
| 09        |  B01     |2021-12-07|null    |file1   |B01-04  |
| 01        |  B02     |null      |null    |file2   |B02-01  |
| 09        |  B02     |2021-12-07|null    |file2   |B02-02  |
| 01        |  B03     |null      |null    |file3   |B03-01  |
| 06        |  B03     |foo       |bar     |file3   |B03-02  |
| 06        |  B03     |foo       |bar     |file3   |B03-03  |
| 09        |  B03     |2021-12-07|null    |file3   |B03-04  |
| 01        |  B01     |null      |null    |file4   |B01-01  |
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file4   |B01-02  |
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file4   |B01-03  |
| 09        |  B01     |2021-12-06|null    |file4   |B01-04  |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

One physical file contains multiple logical files in it and has a header (01), detail_rec (06) and trailer (09) (sometimes only header and trailer)

I want to take the date from the trailer for every logical separation and add that as a column to that block of records as shown below.

```
+-----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|c1         |      c2  | c3       |    c4  |    c5  |    c6  | c7       |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| 01        |  B01     |null      |null    |file1   |B01-01  |2021-12-07|
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file1   |B01-02  |2021-12-07|
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file1   |B01-03  |2021-12-07|
| 09        |  B01     |2021-12-07|null    |file1   |B01-04  |2021-12-07|
| 01        |  B02     |null      |null    |file2   |B02-01  |2021-12-05|
| 09        |  B02     |2021-12-05|null    |file2   |B02-02  |2021-12-05|
| 01        |  B03     |null      |null    |file3   |B03-01  |2021-12-07|
| 06        |  B03     |foo       |bar     |file3   |B03-02  |2021-12-07|
| 06        |  B03     |foo       |bar     |file3   |B03-03  |2021-12-07|
| 09        |  B03     |2021-12-07|null    |file3   |B03-04  |2021-12-07|
| 01        |  B01     |null      |null    |file4   |B01-01  |2021-12-06|
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file4   |B01-02  |2021-12-06|
| 06        |  B01     |foo       |bar     |file4   |B01-03  |2021-12-06|
| 09        |  B01     |2021-12-06|null    |file4   |B01-04  |2021-12-06|
+-----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

I tried the Window functionality to extract the rowsBetween using unboundedPreceding and unboundedFollowing, but couldn't reach anywhere.

Comment: Hoow are rows uniquely identified in your dataframe?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn’t!

Comment: In case I had , how would It work?

Comment: If each logical file is identifiable by a unique identifier then you can apply a self join with the identifier and choose `c3` from the df on the right side of the join such that `c1` is `09`. If you can edit the question with column to uniquely a logical file, I can provide a working example.

Comment: Added a unique column, Thanks

Comment: Added unique column c5, Also added c6 to remove duplicates after self-joining

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the `trailer` records from the original df and then rename `c3` column as `c7`. Finally join the original dataframe and the filtered dataframe on the filename column `c5`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("01", "B01", None, None,"file1", "B01-01"),
("06", "B01", "foo", "bar" ,"file1", "B01-02"),
("06", "B01", "foo", "bar" ,"file1", "B01-03"),
("09", "B01", "2021-12-07", None,"file1", "B01-04"),
("01", "B02", None, None,"file2", "B02-01"),
("09", "B02", "2021-12-05", None,"file2", "B02-02"),
("01", "B03", None, None,"file3", "B03-01"),
("06", "B03", "foo", "bar" ,"file3", "B03-02"),
("06", "B03", "foo", "bar" ,"file3", "B03-03"),
("09", "B03", "2021-12-07", None,"file3", "B03-04"),
("01", "B01", None, None,"file4", "B01-01"),
("06", "B01", "foo", "bar" ,"file4", "B01-02"),
("06", "B01", "foo", "bar" ,"file4", "B01-03"),
("09", "B01", "2021-12-06", None,"file4", "B01-04"),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", )) 

df_trailer = df.selectExpr("c5", "c3 as c7").filter(F.col("c1") == "09")

df.join(df_trailer, ["c5"]).show()
```

### Output

```
+-----+---+---+----------+----+------+----------+
|   c5| c1| c2|        c3|  c4|    c6|        c7|
+-----+---+---+----------+----+------+----------+
|file1| 01|B01|      null|null|B01-01|2021-12-07|
|file1| 06|B01|       foo| bar|B01-02|2021-12-07|
|file1| 06|B01|       foo| bar|B01-03|2021-12-07|
|file1| 09|B01|2021-12-07|null|B01-04|2021-12-07|
|file2| 01|B02|      null|null|B02-01|2021-12-05|
|file2| 09|B02|2021-12-05|null|B02-02|2021-12-05|
|file3| 01|B03|      null|null|B03-01|2021-12-07|
|file3| 06|B03|       foo| bar|B03-02|2021-12-07|
|file3| 06|B03|       foo| bar|B03-03|2021-12-07|
|file3| 09|B03|2021-12-07|null|B03-04|2021-12-07|
|file4| 01|B01|      null|null|B01-01|2021-12-06|
|file4| 06|B01|       foo| bar|B01-02|2021-12-06|
|file4| 06|B01|       foo| bar|B01-03|2021-12-06|
|file4| 09|B01|2021-12-06|null|B01-04|2021-12-06|
+-----+---+---+----------+----+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me with this. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using Window

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('c5').orderBy('c1').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)
new_df = df.withColumn('c7', sf.last('c3').over(w))
```

Created group based of c5 and then picked the last value of c3. Added that as a new column c7